# Google Visualization API does not work. (Language.html:17 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Query' of undefined)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

I am trying to read a Google Spreadsheet with JavaScript, using the Google Visualization API. In order to do this, I got an API key with 'Add credentials' in Google APIs page of my Google account. I included this key in the src in the first `<script>` element. My code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
    <head>
        <script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?key=AIzaSyDL4CKWGTLo...">
        </script>
        <title>Spreadsheet</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type='text/javascript'>

            function init(){
                var query = new 
   google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bIydJJY_-H9NHHhxca9U-jNmKjYUkln14v20N7klAGg/edit?usp=sharing');
                console.log(query); 
                query.setQuery('select dept, sum(salary) group by dept');
                query.send(handleQueryResponse);
            }; 
            setTimeout(function() {
                init();}, 3000);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have read a lot of questions on Stack Overflow regarding the google visualization API, and the most common problem is a timing problem. Therefore, I put the first `<script>` element as high as possible in the file and I put a timeout on the `init()` function. However, I still get the error: 
*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Query' of undefined
    at init (Language.html:17)
    at Language.html:23*

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to call `load` before using,
try it like this...

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {
  packages: ['corechart'],
  callback: function () {
    var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bIydJJY_-H9NHHhxca9U-jNmKjYUkln14v20N7klAGg/edit?usp=sharing');
    query.setQuery('select dept, sum(salary) group by dept');
    query.send(handleQueryResponse);
  }
});
```

Comment: By the way, you should upgrade your charts to the new loader and more recent versions.  See https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#update-library-loader-code